# Bootstrap 3 responsive not working on mobile of android internet explorer

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap 3.I am testing out Bootstrap 3 responsiveness navbar and I have a website [link](http://freerechargeapp.com/index.html) . When I resize the browser on a desktop, it all works fine including the nav bar which become collapsible menu with a small icon on the top which I can click to see more menu buttons and converted it in to 12 grids as per code.

But when I tried it from my mobile browser (I tried it on internet browser on an Android), I didn't see the responsive design. I could only see very small version of desktop like website.

I have already added this code in head section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

but still its not working.(you can check from your mobile for proof).
Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You set `viewport` incorrect, look `<meta name="“viewport”" content="“width=device-width," intitial-scale="1" maximum-scale="1”">` remove `“` and `”`

Comment: ya you are correct and thanks for your answers actually i have copied from as site. when i write it with sublime editor it is working fine now and thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello friends,
          As waki pointed out my problem that i put meta tag for the viewport is not correct although i have updated here correctly but in my original site i have written like as waki mentioned above. thanks waki for your valuable comment.